# Is there any way to send messages from the command line in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, software-rec, batch-file, messaging

I was doing some tutorials on batch scripting when I came across a command prompt messenger tutorial that explained how to message someone directly from their computer.

I followed the tutorial and then discovered that for some reason, Vista does not allow that function. Is there an alternative to make this possible? I know there is a Windows Messenger type thing already, but I wanted to try it on the command line.

Comment: Which "command prompt messenger"? It is not clear what you are talking about. Please add the link to this tutorial.

Comment: @Robert: He's probably talking about the old Windows Messenger service.

Comment: @mendez: This isn't very clear.  You'll need to be more specific.  Is this message need to be sent to another computer? Another person on the internet?? Another person on AOL??? Another person my snail mail???? Another person sitting behind your shoulder????? A person in front of the computer???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call a simple script file if you want to fire off a dialog box.

Save this as a VBS file:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
messageText = objArgs(0)
MsgBox messageText
```

Or you can use Javascript

```
WScript.Echo(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));
```

Then just run the file from the command line: `wscript myfile.(vb or js) "Hello World!"